# Oracle syntax to return minimum value from timestamp field

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have an Oracle table with a field named `Entrytime`.  This field is defined as `Timestamp(6)`.  How do I query the table to return the minimum `Entrytime` value as a `TimeStamp`?

```
select To_Timestamp(min(entrytime),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') entrytime
from webforms.startstop2013
```

Gives me this error:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found
>   where a numeric was expected
>
> 1858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
>
> *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
>              incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was required by the format model.
>
> *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
>              elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

A general query looks like this:

```
Select entrytime From webforms.StartStop2013;
```

But that returns a `DateTime` value and not a `timestamp` value.

Comment: Looks like you want `TO_CHAR` rather than `To_Timestamp`.

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)? `TO_TIMESTAMP converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2 datatype to a value of TIMESTAMP datatype.`. since entrytime is a timestamp(6), what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Did you try `select min(entrytime) from webforms.startstop2013`? Or do you also need to convert the minimum entrytime to a character string, in a given format? If you need it for further processing, you shouldn't convert it, leave it in timestamp datatype. If it's for reporting/presentation, you will need to wrap within `TO_CHAR()`

Comment: Oh, and regarding your last paragraph: That is not true; if entrytime is a timestamp, then the query returns a timestamp, but your front-end (Toad, SQL*Plus, perhaps an application) doesn't display it that way. How it is displayed depends on your NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT setting.

Comment: Perhaps " How do I query the table to return the minimum Entrytime value as a TimeStamp?" isn't clear enough.  For later processing I need the minimum timestamp value of the entrytime field.  If I query on Min(entrytime) I get a datetime return value. This is not useful.  So, once again,  how do I query the table to return the minimum Entrytime value as a TimeStamp?

Marc B: What are you, two? What I expected to happen is a timestamp return value.  Learn to read.  
I searched for the To_timestamp and read what came up in the results.  It didn't answer my question or I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I need to think about that.

Comment: Mathguy, Thanks for the response but the return value I get is indeed a datetime value and not a timestamp value.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Pro so maybe that is why, but when I copy the query and run it through PLSQL I get a datetime value back as well.  You first response may be the answer I need. I need to investigate.